# General Objects in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers

I need create a general object for using it in some controller, but I don't know how.

This object is a class that have a parameters, constructor and getters/setters but I can't access in other controller.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just create class file in `/application/libraries` and then in controller constructor add loader:

```
$this->load->library('YOU_FILENAME_IN_LOWERCASE');
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean model, and [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) you have everything about it.